# safeTransferFrom is undefined in buidler test

Tags: solidity, erc-721, address.transfer, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I have started using buidler for testing/compiling my contracts. In one test i have setup a scenario that a owner attempts to transfer a token to another wallet address.

My contract is inheriting from the Open Zeppelin ERC721.sol one. When trying to call `token.safeTransferFrom(args)` it says that `safeTransferFrom` is not a a function and when logging it out it shows as `undefined`.

Im pretty new to solidity and smart contract coding but looking through the source I can see that the function declaration looks the same as `approve` which I can call quite happily using `token.approve(args)`.

Is there anything obvious that Im missing?

Comment: Can you find `safeTransferFrom` function in the contract ABI?

Comment: @ChenchenYo Yes I can see it in there

Comment: What's your code? Maybe token is not properly initialized.

Answer (score 10):

Ran into this myself as well. Are you using `ethers.js` with Buidler?

The `safeTransferFrom` method is overloaded and generally with `ethers.js` the bare definition is [the default method used](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/407#issuecomment-458329708).

If you run `console.log( Object.keys(token) )` you'll see the methods on the `token` and you'll likely see two definitions of `safeTransferFrom`. Pick the one you want to use then you can call it like this:

```js
token['safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)'](fromAddr, toAddr, tokenId);
```

Comment: Thank you Dan-Nolan. if using a different caller:       await token.connect(user1)['safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)'](userX, userY, 1);